# Return token string from alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json, django-rest-auth

I'm traying to save a temporary token stored in to my django-rest framework to do some GET/POST requests. This is my code:

```
class API {

    let apiBaseUrl = "https://myhost.tld"

    func getToken(loginData: NSDictionary ,completionHandler: (NSDictionary?, NSError?) -> ()) {
        makePOST(loginData, section: "api-token-auth", completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    func getList(tokenStr: String, completionHandler: (NSDictionary?, NSError?) -> ()) {
        makeGET(tokenStr, section: "api/list", completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }

    func makePOST(login: NSDictionary, section: String, completionHandler: (NSDictionary?, NSError?) -> ()) {

        Alamofire.request(.POST, "\(apiBaseUrl)/\(section)/", parameters: login as! [String : String])
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .Success(let value):
                    completionHandler(value as? NSDictionary, nil)
                case .Failure(let error):
                    completionHandler(nil, error)
                }
        }
    }

    func makeGET(token: String?=nil, section: String, completionHandler: (NSDictionary?, NSError?) -> ()) {

        Alamofire.request(.POST, "\(apiBaseUrl)/\(section)/", headers: ["Authorization":"Token \(token)"])
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .Success(let value):
                    completionHandler(value as? NSDictionary, nil)
                case .Failure(let error):
                    completionHandler(nil, error)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

So when i create an object type API() and I can view returned my token when i call getToken but i dont know how to store this to pass it to api.getList(token) function:

```
let api = API()
api.getToken(["username":"blah","password":"blah"]) { responseObject, error in
        debugPrint("responseObject = \(responseObject!["token"])")
        return
}...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to store the token locally in your device?

Comment: @Daniel you can store your token in a variable in your completion handler

Comment: I can store in keychain but its better pass as variable to next function. How can i put a new variable in completion handler and store globally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
let api = API()
    api.getToken(["username":"blah","password":"blah"], { responseObject, error in
            print("responseObject = \(responseObject!["token"])")
            api.getList(responseObject!["token"], { responseObject, error in
      }
    )
    })
```

Comment: Your answer works,  but i must inherit more functions.